# UNION ALL LEFT JOIN and SUM returns incorrect value

Tags: mysql, sum, left-join, union-all

I'm trying to get the inventory amounts of each warehouse on the basis of the inventory code, but the total amounts are returned incorrectly

can you help me find my mistake?

Products

```
+----------+-------------+------------+
| barkod   | stokkodu    |  stokadi   |
+----------+-------------+------------+
| 10057    | U-56544547  |   Çocuk    |
| 10312    | U-56548672  |   Gömlek   |
| 14124    | U-56144681  |   Çanta    |
| 18137    | U-56511551  |   Cüzdan   |
| 17859    | U-16511551  |   Gözlük   |
| 10112    | U-56544672  |   Gömlek   |
| 10124    | U-56544681  |   Çanta    |
| 10137    | U-56545551  |   Cüzdan   |
+----------+-------------+------------+
```

Warehouse 1

```
+----------+-------------+------+
| barkod   | stokkodu    | adet |
+----------+-------------+------+
| 10111    | U-56544664  |   27 |
| 10112    | U-56544672  |  141 |
| 10124    | U-56544681  |   84 |
| 10137    | U-56545551  |  254 |
+----------+-------------+------+
```

Warehouse 2

```
+----------+-------------+------+
| barkod   | stokkodu    | adet |
+----------+-------------+------+
| 10009    | Unknown     |   61 |
| 10112    | U-56544672  |  131 |
| 10124    | U-56544681  |   85 |
| 10137    | U-56545551  |  254 |
+----------+-------------+------+
```

I tried

```
SELECT 
   u.stokkodu, 
   products.stokadi,
   SUM(b.adet) AS stokadet,
   SUM(c.adet) AS sayimadet
   FROM (
      SELECT stokkodu FROM wh1 
      UNION ALL
      SELECT stokkodu FROM wh2 WHERE onay = 1 
   ) u   
   LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT 
          stokkodu, 
          adet 
       FROM wh1 
       GROUP BY stokkodu
   ) b ON u.stokkodu = b.stokkodu
   LEFT JOIN (
       SELECT 
          stokkodu, 
          adet 
       FROM wh2 
       WHERE onay = 1 
       GROUP BY stokkodu
   ) c ON u.stokkodu = c.stokkodu
   LEFT JOIN products ON u.stokkodu = products.stokkodu
GROUP BY u.stokkodu
```

wh1 and wh2 may not have the same products

I desired

```
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| barkod   | stokkodu    |  stokadi   | stokadet | sayimadet |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+
| 10111    | U-56544664  |  Gömlek    |     27   |     0     |
| 10112    | U-56544672  |  Gözlük    |     141  |     131   |
| 10124    | U-56544681  |  Ayakkabı  |     84   |     85    |
| 10137    | U-56545551  |  Çanta     |     254  |     254   |
| 10009    | Unknown     |  Unknown   |     0    |     61    |
+----------+-------------+------------+----------+-----------+
```

**Thank you**

Comment: Some of the columns to which you refer in your query do not match with the sample tables you gave above.

Comment: it would be a lot easier if you'd give us a sample of your desired output

Comment: Does it work if you replace UNION ALL with UNION?

Comment: I added desired out out and different incorrect values with UNION

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the right values with this query

```
SELECT
d.barkod, 
x.stokkodu,
d.stokadi,
IFNULL(b.stokadet,0) AS "stokadet",
IFNULL(c.adet,0) AS "sayimadet"
FROM (  
     SELECT stokkodu FROM wh1 
     UNION ALL 
     SELECT stokkodu FROM wh2 WHERE onay = 1 
) x 
LEFT JOIN ( 
     SELECT 
     stokkodu, 
     IFNULL(SUM(adet),0) as stokadet 
     FROM wh1 
     GROUP BY stokkodu 
) b ON x.stokkodu = b.stokkodu 
LEFT JOIN ( 
     SELECT 
     stokkodu, 
     IFNULL(SUM(adet),0) as sayimadet 
     FROM wh2 
     WHERE onay = 1 
     GROUP BY stokkodu  
) c ON x.stokkodu = c.StokKodu 
LEFT JOIN products d ON x.stokkodu = d.stokkodu 
GROUP BY x.stokkodu
```